# How to map JSON response to Vue routes?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I have an API that responds with a JSON like this:

```
{
    "Thriller": "Thriller books",
    "Biographical": "Biographical books",
    "Romance": "Romance books"
}
```

I would like to end up with routes like this:

```
http://example.com/thriller
http://example.com/biographical
http://example.com/romance
```

Essentially, the API should dictate what kind of books are available to see. Afterwards `Books` component will display generic data about specific book types. I got this far with my router configuration:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Home from './views/Home.vue';
import Books from './views/Books.vue';

Vue.use(Router);

var books: Record<string, string> = await fetch('http://example.com/api/available-books')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        return data;
    });


export default new Router({ 
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: books.map((shortname: string, fullname: string) => ({ component: Books, path: `/${shortname}`)),
});
```

However TS linter says there are two problems with `map()`: `TS1005: comma expected` at the end of the line and `TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression - type String has no invocation signature` (roughly translated).

I don't understand what I should do. Maybe there's a better way to do what I'm trying? I'm new at SPA stuff.

Comment: what exactly is the error message? and is the data from response.json() coming in as an array when you log it?

Comment: @altruios There are two errors: `TS1005: comma expected` at the end of the line and `TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression - type String has no invocation signature` (roughly translated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use the route you're taking, this may be a cleaner way to generate the routes.

```js
const books = {
    "Thriller": "Thriller books",
    "Biographical": "Biographical books",
    "Romance": "Romance books"
}

const output = Object.entries(books).map(book => {
  const [shortname, fullname] = book
  return { component: 'Books', path: `/${shortname.toLowerCase()}` } 
})

console.log(output)
```

Otherwise, I would recommend using [dynamic route matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#dynamic-route-matching) to pass the book ID into the component rather than making a blocking API call on page load.

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/book/:shortname', component: Book }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

ah... looking above at the format of your json... the reason map isn't working is because it's a giant object. and map only works for arrays.

two solutions... format the json as an array... such as

```
{
    "Thriller": "Thriller books",
    "Biographical": "Biographical books",
    "Romance": "Romance books"
}
const mappedToArray  = [];
for (const prop in json) {
    mappedToArray.push({[prop]:json[prop]});
}
console.log(mappedToArray) 
// output is:> Array [
//Object { Thriller: "Thriller books" },
// Object { Biographical: "Biographical books" },
// Object { Romance: "Romance books" }
//]
```

or instead of map. use: Object.keys to get an array from an object that you can then iterate over with map.

```
Object.keys(json).map(function(key, index) {
//your code here
});
```

Comment: I tried the first solution and it still says a comma was expected at the end.

Comment: if you output the json - that is literally the format above?
if you use
Object.keys(json).map(function(key, index) {
console.log(key+" "+index);
});
what is the output?

Comment: the unexpected token comes up for me in codepen.io when i copy/paste the json structure... when I assign it to a variable that goes away.
causes error:

```
{
    "Thriller": "Thriller books",
    "Biographical": "Biographical books",
    "Romance": "Romance books"
}
```
does not cause error 

```
const books = {
    "Thriller": "Thriller books",
    "Biographical": "Biographical books",
    "Romance": "Romance books"
}
```